# Session object storing JWT + handling refresh tokens in node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I am building my application using Angular and node.js (express) and I am using JWT for authentication and authorization. Currently, I am storing JWT in session object on server in memory `(req.session.jwt = user.generateToken())` and also, I am sending refresh token in HttpOnly cookie to the client.

When JWT expires, I want server to give me new JWT, if refresh token from cookie is equal to the refresh token in database - asociated with user.

I tried to implement refresh token logic in my auth middleware in the catch block, but it did not work.

*(If token validation failed, then compare RF token from cookie to RF in database, if true, set new JWT and run the routehandler.)*

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.session.jwt;

  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied.");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    (async () => {
      let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.session.username });
      if (!user) return res.status(500).send("Invalid session");

      if (user.refreshToken === req.signedCookies.refreshToken) {
        req.session.jwt = user.generateToken();
        next();
      } else {
        return res.status(401).send("Invalid session");
      }
    })();
  }
};
```

I had implemented this refresh token logic, when I was storing token and refresh token in localstorage on client, but this was not great implementation, so I tried to make it like this.
I had token.interceptor in my Angular part of the project - from this tutorial (https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/#refresh-token)

Here is my github repo of the backend https://github.com/TenPetr/dashboard_backend

If you have any idea, how to implement this logic, please let me know.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: What error did you get? Did you check if this variable (req.signedCookies.refreshToken) has the right value?

Comment: @David Vicente It simply did not return value from route handler... Yeaa, values was fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a new JWT token, as the request is going to continue to next middleware step, probably you will need to set the user, same as you do when the jwt is correct.
Something like this, try it, and let me know if it helps:

```
if (user.refreshToken === req.signedCookies.refreshToken) {
  req.session.jwt = user.generateToken();
  const decoded = jwt.verify(req.session.jwt, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));
  req.user = decoded;
  next();
}
```

Comment: It helped! Thanks a lot! And... do you think that this is good solution for handling refresh and JWT tokens?

Comment: I don't think so. I think it would be better if the refresh token action would be done as a different REST request. Because right now you are sending token and refresh token in the same request together, so it is useless from the security point of view.

Comment: Hmm.. and is it useless even if JWT is stored in memory on server? I am only sending two httpOnly cookies from client - session id + refresh token

Comment: But refresh token should be only sent when you need to use, it is like your master key. If anyone intercepts one of your requests, it would be generate as many tokens as it wants and works on your behalf. That's the security problem

Comment: Understand... and do you have any link or something where can I read about best practices? I didnt find anything great.. everybody is writing about local storage ...

Comment: And what if I set cookiePath to only "/auth/token", so this cookie will be send only to this route..

Comment: If you do that, you have to make sure that always the token is expired, you call that path. Take a look to this article, it is oriented to Node.js, but maybe it helps you to clarify concepts: https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-node-js/